# How to convert the Stream to base64 string for NodeJS in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, image, base64

I'm using axis to download the image as following:

```js
private async downloadImage(imageUrl: string): Promise<Stream> {
  const response = await axios.get<Stream>(imageUrl, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
    },
    responseType: 'stream',
  });
  return response.data;
}
```

How can I convert the "Stream" object to "base64 string" I get from this RESTFul API in NodeJS? Because I need to attach this image to send the mail (by nodemailer) to the user. Example,

```
attachments: [
  {
    filename: 'image.jpg',
    path: 'data:image/png;base64,[base64Image]',
    cid: 'image',
  },
],
```

How can I achieve it for NodeJS in TypeScript?

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I find the method to convert it by pass through the Stream:

```js
static async streamToBase64(stream: Stream): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const cbConcat = (base64) => {
      resolve(base64);
    };

  stream
    .pipe(new Base64Encode())
    .pipe(concat(cbConcat))
    .on('error', (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}
```

However, the Stream could be used once... Anyone know how to clone it to consume it again?